# Is it possible to make a #has_one polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, polymorphism

I have an application where people play quizzes. Quizzes can have many questions, which can be of different kind ("true or false", a choice amongst a set provided answers etc.).

The way I found it best to implement this is to have a `Question` model (and `questions` table), and then I keep its data in different tables, depending on what kind of question it is. For example, if it's a "true or false" question, then it will keep its data in

```
create_table :boolean_question_data do |t|
  t.boolean :answer
end
```

And if it's an "image" question, for example, then it will keep its data in

```
create_table :image_question_data do |t|
  t.attachment :image
  t.string :image
end
```

And so on.

So, one way I wanted to implement this (I'm open to suggestions :)) is that the `questions` table has columns `#id` and `#category`, and the "data" tables (`boolean_question_data`, `image_question_data`) have a `#question_id` column (and **no** primary key), and I also have this in my `Question` model:

```
has_one :data, polymorphic: true
```

The reason why I want to do it like this is because I want questions to have a unique primary key, regardless of the category. So, I want to have normal URLs like `/questions/3`, and the `Question` model will just search for the `#id` of 3, and see that the `#category` is i.e. "boolean", and then it knows that it has to search for its data in the `boolean_question_data` table.

The reason why I **can't** use a polymorphic `belongs_to` (instead of `has_one`) is because it isn't intended for that kind of usage. It doesn't provide me with `#build_data`, `#create_data` etc, instead it expects me to write my code the other way around, that is to reference the question from "data" models. This is obviously not something I want to do.

I would write that association myself, but I also want to use a lot of options (`autosave: true, validate: true, dependent: :destroy`), so it would be a bit of an overkill to write all that manually.

Do you have any suggestions for me?